# Scheduled Task for robocopy PowerShell script does not finish - what's wrong?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, robocopy

I'm working on a PowerShell script to automatically move some files to a remote server every 5 minutes.

The logs are always nested two directories deep.  I don't care about those directories.  Both the folders and the files can be, but are not always, randomly named.  I have used the local temp directory to accomplish the de-nesting prior to shuttling the files over to `robocopy`.

I've also created a new event log source for troubleshooting.  I'll cut those down after I can get this working.  I believe I'm running this from Task Scheduler correctly (as start a program `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` with arguments `-WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\PathToScript\ThisIsTheScript.ps1"`).

Here's how it should go when automated.

1. Triggered by Task Scheduler
2. Create temp log directory if needed
3. De-nest and move logs to temp log directory
4. Remove all empty directories from source
5. `robocopy` to destination share by UNC name
6. Task Scheduler completes task

The files remain in the temp log directory, do not copy to the destination server, and Task Scheduler never completes - it remains running.  However, all of the troubleshooting log entries are created, even if using `Start-Job` and `Wait-Job` around the `robocopy` line.

Steps 5 and 6 are not happening when scheduled, only when run manually.  Why aren't the files copying, and why won't the task complete when run in Task Scheduler?

```
# Source Variables
$LogSource  = 'C:\Somewhat\Deeper\Directory\Log\Files\Dropped\Here'
$TempLogDir = 'C:\SomeFilesBrieflyHere'

# Destination variables
$DestHost   = 'thisisthedestinationcomputername'
$DestShare  = 'thisisthedestinationsharename$'

# Operating Variables
$Switches   = @("/s", "/MOVE", "/zb", "/R:0", "/W:0", "/MT:8", "/NFL", "/NDL", "/NP", "/IS", "/IT")
$RoboDo     = @("$TempLogDir","\\$DestHost\$DestShare","$Switches")

# Verify event log source exists and create it if it does not
if (-not ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists("PowerShell Script"))) {
    New-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -Source 'PowerShell Script'
    Write-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -Source 'Powershell Script' -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Message 'Created new Event Log: Application Source type: PowerShell Script'
}

# Write log for init
Write-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -Source 'Powershell Script' -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Message 'The scheduled task to move logs to the log server has been triggered and will now execute.'

# Verify Local LogDir exists
if (!(Test-Path -Path $TempLogDir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TempLogDir
} 

# De-nest logs to local log folder in preparation to move
Get-ChildItem -Path "$LogSource" | Get-ChildItem | Get-ChildItem | Move-Item -Destination "$TempLogDir" -Force
Write-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -Source 'Powershell Script' -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Message "Files locally de-nested into $TempLogDir."

# Remove all empty directories with unicorn glitter
Get-ChildItem $LogSource -Recurse | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath:$_.FullName).Count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Force
Get-ChildItem $TempLogDir -Recurse | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath:$_.FullName).Count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Force
Write-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -Source 'Powershell Script' -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Mes

# Begin Robocopy operation
robocopy $TempLogDir \\$DestHost\$DestShare $Switches
Write-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -Source 'Powershell Script' -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Message "The scheduled task to move logs to the log server has been completed and the files were successfully copied to $DestHost."
```

Comment: Have `robocopy` write a log, so that you can see where it stalls (or if it even runs in the first place). Also try mapping the share to a drive letter instead of using an UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the robocopy line to this instead:
        `& robocopy $TempLogDir \\$DestHost\$DestShare $Switches`
The problem might be that your script stops at that line, complaining that robocopy isn't a cmdlet or function, even though it works when running it manually.

Comment: That's what I was thinking!  Will update/rate shortly.